# Can I use classes or lists to make my code more efficient?

Tags: python, list, class, pygame

I am making a 2D game in python using pygame. I have made 4 different circles that move across the screen and loop back to the start when they hit the wall. This is not only for cosmetic purposes but it also counts the score. I want to simplify it and I feel like a could use a list or class or something.

```
capimg = pygame.image.load('cap.png')
cy = 575
cx1 = 200
cx2 = 400
cx3 = 600
cx4 = 800
```

From here on is inside the game loop

```
    cx1 += speed
    cx2 += speed
    cx3 += speed
    cx4 += speed
    if cx1 <= -20:
        score += 1
        print(score)
        cx1 = 800
    if cx2 <= -20:
        score += 1
        print(score)
        cx2 = 800
    if cx3 <= -20:
        score += 1
        print(score)
        cx3 = 800
    if cx4 <= -20:
        score += 1
        print(score)
        cx4 = 800
    screen.blit(capimg, (cx1, cy))
    screen.blit(capimg, (cx2, cy))
    screen.blit(capimg, (cx3, cy))
    screen.blit(capimg, (cx4, cy))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of x cooridnates:

```py
lx = [200 + i*200 for i in range(4)]
```

Change the coordinates in a loop:

```py
for i in range(len(lx)):
    lx[i] += speed
    if lx[i] <= -20:
        score += 1
        print(score)
        lx[i] = 800
```

Draw the cars in a loop:

```py
for cx in lx:
    screen.blit(capimg, (cx, cy))
```